# How to split string by regular expression in posgres

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql, split

I want to obtain a result similar as split_part function. For example, I have:
database column address:

```
1235 S CLARK ST Suite 109
1240 S CLARK RD Suite 110
```

if I want to split them by street type with split_part function and obtain first part of the array I could say:

```
split_part(address,'ST',1)
split_part(address,'RD',1)
```

So, my question is how can I split the address by street type using a regular expression or another solution in just one line? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working with address data can be very tricky, as the format can vary widely.  We need to see more sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want everything from the start of the string to "ST" or "RD", you can use use `substring()` like that:

```
select substring(address from '(.*)\s+(?:ST|RD)') as first_part
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=49975eea03cff46d9ac61ed53dc383b6)**:

```
select address, substring(address from '(.*)\s+(?:ST|RD)') as first_part
from (values ('1235 S CLARK ST Suite 109'), ('1240 S CLARK RD Suite 110')) t(address)
```

```
address                   | first_part   
:------------------------ | :------------
1235 S CLARK ST Suite 109 | 1235 S CLARK 
1240 S CLARK RD Suite 110 | 1240 S CLARK
```